# How to preview other content types in titanium desktop

Tags: html, titanium

I am using titanium to build a desktop application. They are a couple of times I need to download an excel file (or any other content type).

I am expecting it to open a file chooser dialog so I choose a folder to save it in. Instead it displays the content of the excel file in the desktop window which is not very useful.

I am able to view PDF files correctly in the desktop window. 
How do I download regular files from titanium.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but I don't think you can control this behavior. This is based on each client machine that is using your application and their specific settings. Maybe [this forum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/723516-prevent-excel-files-for-opening-in-internet-explorer.html) will help.

It may also depend on the content headers of the source of your file. If you need a reference for how a web application can be configured to force a download, [see here](http://aspalliance.com/259_downloading_files__forcing_the_file_download_dialog). While this is based on a web app, the same MIME type rules apply.